# Make image inside a list item fire functions associated with larger list item?

Tags: jquery, html, css, image, list

I have list items with empty checkbox images to the left of each item. I have these li styled like selectors (see picture below).

Can I attach the image of the empty checkbox to the list item so that all clicks on the image fire any functions associated with clicking the larger list item? Right now, clicking anywhere in the selector except for the image fires the click function, but I want the user to be able to click throughout the entire selector.

```
<ul>
  <li id="opt1" class="list_header"> <img id="emptcheck1" src="images/emptycheckbox.png" /> option 1 </li>
  <li id="opt2" class="list_header">  <img id="emptcheck2" src="images/emptycheckbox.png" /> option 2 </li>
</ul>
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can wrap the whole thing inside an `<a>` tag or, give the click handler to the `<li>` itself.

**Type 1**

JavaScript

```
$(".list_header").click(function(){
    ...
});
```

CSS

```
.list_header {cursor: pointer;}
```

**Type 2**

HTML

```
<ul>
  <li id="opt1" class="list_header"><a href="#"><img id="emptcheck1" src="images/emptycheckbox.png" /> option 1</a></li>
  <li id="opt2" class="list_header"><a href="#"><img id="emptcheck2" src="images/emptycheckbox.png" /> option 2</a></li>
</ul>
```

JavaScript

```
$(".list_header a").click(function(){
    ...
});
```

CSS

```
.list_header a {display: block;}
```

Comment: Thank you! thought it might be pretty simple.

Comment: @John Actually this is the simplest solution. :) You can make it complex, by building on this. :)